# Request parameter encoding seems to not be set to UTF-8

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, facelets, servlet-filters

I have a simple xhtml page produced by a Netbeans 7.3.1 template from an Entity class, hosted in Glassfish 4. The Entity class only contains two fields, an `ID` and a `Name`. If I write in the field 'Name' the word "`café`" then it saves "`cafÃ©`". I have followed every recommendation posted on the internet, but all have failed miserably. None of them have worked, at least not for JSF 2.2.

I tried creating a custom filter; using the Spring `CharacterEncodingFilter` filter, the headers all contain the charset->UTF-8. I checked with Firebug the charset of the page and it says UTF-8.

I'm running out of ideas. Anybody have any?

BTW, the same website project contains a RESTful web-service, and the web-service works perfectly saving the same entity and the same value (`café`). So, this leads me to the conclusion that the problem is in the Facelets, but where?

I am using this filter:

```
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

and the `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UTFEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UTFEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Something tells me this filter is not being used, I placed a `throw Exception` on `Init` method, and the pages load and post normally.

Comment: @BalusC, you have to stop trolling good QA posts. Can you see what you're doing? you say the correct answer is wrong, you say I am the problem, then you call me stupid, you change a good post title that was showing the specific version of JSF I'm using, and finally you post an answer that does not work for this version of JSF (I tried without the Exceptions). What is wrong with you? You may offer new suggestions if you want, but disqualifying other people work won't get you anywhere.

Comment: The answer shows a Glassfish-specific solution, not a JSF-specific solution and is therefore not portable; I didn't call you stupid directly in person, just that you "look like" stupid with the combination of the original title and code; the JSF version is already mentioned in question; you didn't mention that you tried without exceptions. My answer works for me, otherwise I didn't post it. Apparently there's more at matter in your environment. Perhaps you're using PrimeFaces? Or perhaps you're actually dealing with GET requests instead of POST requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try put your encoding in the server configuration file itself.For Example in glassfish-web.xml put this line

```
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: To verify in `web.xml` also.

Comment: Technically, considering the question, this isn't a solution but a workaround. And it would still fail if the webapp is deployed to a different server make/version.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is an old question , but i have faced this problem a few days ago , i am working with glassfish 4 .

what i did is the following :

1. in my project under WEB-INF , i created an xml file called "glassfish-web.xml".
2. in the glassfish-web.xml i added the parameter-encoding tag , with the accept-charset equals to UTF-8 , like the following :

```
<glassfish-web-app>

   <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>

</glassfish-web-app>
```

Hope that will help someone , because at first i thought the "glassfish-web.xml" is already creted with the glassfish files , then i realized , that i have to create it within my project .

Answer (score 0):

Your concrete problem is caused because your filter failed to initialize and is therefore never been placed in service.

Your filter failed to initialize for the very simple reason because you threw an exception in `init()` method.

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

You shouldn't be throwing an exception in `init()` if you'd like the filter to successfully initialize.

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // NOOP.
}
```